# Prove that if A and B are equivalent matrices and C and D are equivalent matrices, A⊕C is equivalent to B⊕D.

Tags: matrices, direct-sum

Given: A, B ∈ Mn(F) and C, D ∈ Mm(F)

A and B are equivalent, so are C and D.

Im not sure how to approach this.

But since A is equivalent to B and C is equivalent to D, there exist P, Q ∈ Mn(F) and S, T ∈ Mm(F)such that A = PBQ and C = SDT.

To prove that A⊕C is equivalent to B⊕D, do I show that there exist an X, Y ∈ M(m+n)(F) such that A⊕C = X(B⊕D)Y?

If so, how?

Comment: By direct sum $A⊕B$ do you mean the block diagonal matrix diag($A,B$) ?

Comment: Yes, it's the block diagonal matrix A,B @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your notation:

$$A\oplus C=\left[\begin{matrix}A&0\\0&C\end{matrix}\right], B\oplus D=\left[\begin{matrix}B&0\\0&D\end{matrix}\right]$$

then you can certainly do that. The solution is:

$$X=\left[\begin{matrix}P&0\\0&S\end{matrix}\right]=P\oplus S$$

and

$$Y=\left[\begin{matrix}Q&0\\0&T\end{matrix}\right]=Q\oplus T$$

Comment: thank you! I knew X and Y had to be composed of P,S,Q,T but I couldn't solve it.